# Step in the proof of the strong law of large numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ i.i.d. and $\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)< \infty$, w.l.o.g. $\mathbb{E}(X_1) = 0$. This in turn implies:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq n) \leq \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq t) \ dt =  \mathbb{E} (|X_1|)< \infty
$$

Now my professor argues that by Borel-Cantelli, a.s. $|X_n| \leq n$ for $n$ large enough, thus we have, except on a set of probability zero, $X_n \chi_{|X_n|\leq n}=X_n$ (where $\chi_{|X_n|\leq n}$ is the characteristic function on $\{\omega: |X_n(\omega)|\leq n\}$).  Then the proof of the SLLN continues.

I tried to formalise this: By B.C. I.:

\begin{equation}
        \mathbb{P}\left(\lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{\omega \ : \ |X_n(\omega)| < n\}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} \{\omega \ : \ |X_n(\omega)| < n\}\right)=1
    \end{equation}

I.e.
\begin{equation}
        \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \ | \ \exists N \ \forall n \geq N: \ |X_n(\omega)| < n \})=1
    \end{equation}

How does my professor come to the conclusion:
$$
\exists N \ \forall n \geq N:\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \ | \ |X_n(\omega)| < n \}) = 1
$$

This is a way stronger statement, isn’t it? Or is he saying something different?

Comment: The ordering of the words is very key. You wrote: "a.s. $|X_n|\le n$ for $n$ large enough". To me, that's saying: the probability that there exists $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $|X_n|\le n$, i.e. the first interpretation (which follows immediately from Borel Cantelli). I think your professor meant that one and it's also the one you wrote. My hunch is that the second interpretation is false in general

Comment: Your professor didn't come to the conclusion $\exists_N \forall_{n \ge N} \mathbb P(|X_n| < n) = 1$, but to $\mathbb P( \exists_N \forall_{n \ge N} |X_n| < n) = 1$, as you did. Note that for any $\omega$ in this set (of measure $1$) there is some $N = N(\omega)$ such that for all $n \ge N(\omega)$ you have $|X_n(\omega)| < n$ which is precisely what it states.

Comment: But then I dont understand the characteristic function… There it looks like he fixes a $n$ that then is valid for all $\omega$.

Comment: This characteristic function is itself a random variable, i.e $\omega \mapsto \chi_{\{|X_n(\omega)| < n\}}$ which appears to be $1$ for $n \ge N(\omega)$ (where $N(\omega)$ as in my comment above) and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Im a bit confused now, should I read it as $\omega \mapsto (x \mapsto \chi_{\{|X_n(\omega) < n|\}}(x))$ or $\omega \mapsto \chi_{\{|X_n(\omega) < n|\}}(\omega)$

Comment: The second (and there is no need of second $\omega$), there is no $x$ in your functions, the domain is $\Omega$. To be more precise, instead of $\chi_{\{|X_n(\omega)|<n\}}$ you could write $\chi_{(-n,n)} (X_n(\omega))$ i.e. you're evaluating function $\chi_{(-n,n)} \circ X_n$ at the point $\omega$.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, thank you:) But do you get why, using this notation it suffices to show that that a.s. $(X_1‘ + \dots +X_n‘)/n \rightarrow 0$, where $X_n‘ := X_n \chi_{|X_n|<n}$ to show the SLLN?

Comment: because for all $\omega$ in this liminf as above (so almost surely), those sums $X_1'(\omega) + ... X_n'(\omega)$ and $X_1(\omega) + ... + X_n(\omega)$ are the same up to at most $N(\omega)$ terms (we already know that for $n \ge N(\omega)$ there holds $X_n'(\omega) = X_n(\omega)$, so in particular after dividing by $n$ those two limits shall be the same.

Comment: Ok I think this makes sense to me, thank you so much for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until
\begin{equation}
        \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \ | \ \exists N \ \forall n \geq N: \ |X_n(\omega)| < n \})=1
    \end{equation}
it is correct. It means that almost surely, for $\omega\in\Omega$ there exists $N_\omega\in\mathbb N$ such that $\vert X_n(\omega)\vert<n$ for all integers $n\ge N_\omega$. It is this fact that you then use in the proof. You did not write the dependence of $N$ in $\omega$, and wrote simply $N$ instead of $N_\omega$, but that is for convenience, not because the dependence does not exist.

Of course you cannot deduce that
$$
\exists N \ \forall n \geq N:\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \ | \ |X_n(\omega)| < n \}) = 1,
$$
which tells you the same as above except that you can choose a universal $N$ which does not depend on the choice of $\omega$, which is a much stronger statement. More convenient, but not needed.

Comment: But what is meant with the characteristic function then, there he fixes an $n$, doesn’t he? In case his original notes help: https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2023/hs/401-3601-00L/files/chapter3.pdf, the relevant part is on page 8.

Comment: It should be understood as for almost surely all $\omega\in\Omega$, for all $n\ge N_\omega$, $X_n(\omega)\chi_{|X_n(\omega)|\leq n}=X_n(\omega)$, where $N_\omega$ is the integer I mentioned in my answer. Does this equation still trouble you?

Comment: Ok but why is it then enough to show that a.s. $(X_1‘ + \dots +X_n‘)/n \rightarrow 0$, where $X_n‘ := X_n \chi_{|X_n|<n}$ to show the SLLN?

Comment: Because if $u_n=v_n$ for $n$ large enough, or equivalently if they differ for finitely many $n$, then if $(u_1+\cdots+ u_n)/n$ converges to some $\ell\in\mathbb R$ then so does $(v_1+\cdots+v_n)/n$.

Comment: You’re right, this makes sense, thank you:)